# What thresholds apply for labelling of possible contaminants in a sanitizing product?

Tags: labeling, safety, hand-sanitizers

In labelling an isopropanol hand sanitizer in the UK (which I gather would be regulated as a biocide in the EU, not a cosmetic), should a contaminant of one of the ingredients be listed on my ingredients label? Sepimax Zen lists 1-5% 2-methylpropan-2-ol on its SDS as a contaminant. This would be 100-500ppm in the final product. The hazard symbols at least would be the same, because it's similar to the isopropanol, but should it be listed on the ingredients section, too?

Should this be on my SDS but not label? I'm not making a product for sale, so I'm not familiar with the regulations and just trying to get familiar as a exercise, really.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: I think this is probably too much of a legal question rather than a medical sciences one.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds fair enough, and I'm happy to update with more information on the research that I've done. I have, for instance, looked up the SDS for all ingredients, the regulations for preparing an SDS, and parts of the EU biocide directive, which, not being a lawyer, I found rather impenetrable. I will gather links and quotes when I find the time. I saw the labelling tag and thought this would be the right place. Any suggestions where I could ask something like this? I thought there might be an engineer's rule of thumb for something like this, rather than getting deep into the law.